# Problem with GDS export of a layout in Agilent Advanced System Design (ADS)

Tags: layout

I have a problem exporting my layout design in ADS. It gives me an error that the layer map file not found in the library and it creates an empty file.

I'd appreciate if you could let me know what this layer map is and how it is created.

Thank you,

Comment: **Do not** make edits which replace an original poster's descriptive language with obscure abbreviations.

Comment: Look in ADS's help files to figure out how to create a layer map file. Alternatively, you can let ADS automap them for you. Select options at the export window and experiment with the automap options.

Comment: @curtis, Thanks for your answer. I tried using the automap but I still get the following error. An empty GDS file is created.


Automap (GDS Datatype set to 0)

Writing GDSII file C:\ADS_design\Layout_v4_wrk\mfg\Layout_v4_lib_XYZ_V4\gdsii\XYZ_V4.gds

Warnings occurred during translation:

ERROR: (OASTRM-10034): Unable to read file "C:/ADS_design". Verify that the path is specified correctly and that the file is readable.
Time elapsed: 0.02 seconds
Messages:  1 errors, 0 warnings.


Export complete.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen that error before. It's weird. Kind of sounds like a permissions error. Have you tried saving it somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

The layer map is a file that has information on how to convert layout information [from one format to another](http://www-bsac.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cadence/tools/layermap.html).

In your case (you're probably trying to export a layout to GDS) you need the layer map file. This file comes with the [PDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_design_kit) of the technology that you are using. Refer to the PDK's documentation for where to find it, or contact whoever created the PDK and ask them to provide one.